# Google drive compile warnings with 1.6 beta

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working with the code from [google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) in visual studio 2012 (C#).  I managed with hours of fiddling around with nuget reference the necessary libraries.

I compiled the test application and got the following warnings:

```
'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient' is obsolete: 'NativeApplicationClient is not supported any more and it's going to be removed in 1.7.0-beta. Consider using the new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package which supports .NET 4, .NET for WindowsStore apps, Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 and Portable Class Libraries as well'

'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.GoogleAuthenticationServer' is obsolete: 'GoogleAuthenticationServer is not supported any more and it's going to be removed in 1.7.0-beta. Consider using the new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package which supports .NET 4, .NET for Windows Store apps, Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 and Portable Class Libraries as well'
'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService.Scopes' is obsolete: 'Use DriveService.Scope instead. This enum is going to be removed in version 1.7.0-beta.'
```

I did not modify the code other than adding in the client_ID and client_secret.  Other than that, it appears to run...

I'll also mention that I am using the nuget Google.Apis.Auth package.

The code behind the DriveService.Scopes warning is using DriveService.Scopes not Google.Apis.DriveService.Scopes (look at the code on the link; mine is the same).

With the google admin api being deprecated and google breaking the old api almost every other week it seems, I'm anxious to get on the new API. However, with what I'm seeing here I'm wondering if that's a good idea or not.  I could be trading the frying pan for the fire.  With that said, what are we supposed to be using if your current example is already obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use the latest version of the library, that's the version that we maintain, provide fixes, new features and so on. You can get it using NuGet.

The sample code in the page you mentioned wasn't updated lately. Take a look in our samples repository (and specifically in the [Drive API sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Drive.Sample/Program.cs?repo=samples)).

Google.Apis.Auth is the right package to use. The reason the old package (Google.Apis.Authentication) is obsolete is based on the fact the we wanted to support different Windows platforms like WP, Windows 8 applications, ASP.NET MVC. We also  simplified the OAuth2 "dance" which was so complicated before.

Last thing - If we make any incompatible changes in the library we document them in our announcement blog, so our users will be able to make the right adjustments . I recommend you subscribing to this blog to get updates about our library.

Hope everything is clear now :)

Comment: thanks; I'll take a look at this.  Do you have sample code for adding users with the new API?

Comment: I wish I would have stumbled on the above example earlier... It was a LOT easier to compile.

Comment: I downloaded the whole sample and got it to compile with very little effort. However, I am still having an issue running this in my VS 2012.  It goes out to google and the redirect URL tries to come back to a dynamic URL.  I've tried forcing that URL in my IDE to no avail. do you know how to force the port in the IDE?

Comment: 1) Do you use Web Application or Installed Application? 2) Do you user ASP.NET MVC \ ASP.NET \ Console Application?

Comment: It's console application but when I run the sample it opens a browser with a random port number associated with it

Comment: Yeah, that's the default behavior. You have another option - to set PromptCodeReceiver (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/PromptCodeReceiver.cs instead of the default local host listener). That will wait for user input to enter the authorization code. If you are interested, I can send you the code you should have. Let me know

Comment: I would love to see this code! Thanks!

However, what I was referring to was running this code within my debugger.  The url path I run it from changes on every execution (eg: http://localhost:43147/testgooglecode) The port in that example changes.  If I go into google and authorize that URL the next time I run the port changes again.

Comment: We generate a new port on every call. It's ok because you use Installed Application (If it is a web application you will need to register every time the new URL which is awful)... You can mimic the default behavior of the GoogleWebAuthoirzationBroker (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs) by initializing a new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp with the PromptCodeReceiver.